# Django rest framework keep user logged in

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an APi that supports log-in functionality and whenever i switch page to index page, user is not logged in anymore at this point i have no idea what am i doing wrong tbh.

this is my views for logging in

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(["POST", "GET"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def login(request):
    username = request.data.get("username")
    password = request.data.get("password")
    if username is None or password is None:
        return Response({'error': 'Please provide both username and password'},
                        status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if not user:
        return Response({'error': 'Invalid Credentials'},
                        status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    request.session.save()
    return Response({'Success': 'Logged in'},
                    status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

and this is a simple test view for index page, my `session.items()` is blank and `request.user` outputs `AnonymousUser`

```
def test_view(request):
    print(request.session.items())
    print(request.user)
    return HttpResponse(request.COOKIES.keys())
```

and in my settings i have

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
),
```

Comment: do you added `django.contrib.sessions` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` and also `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` in MiDDLEWARE ?

Comment: yeap it's all there  !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `login()` your user after authenticate

```py
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if not user:
    . . .
login(request, user)
```